# Is there a package for using attributes to bind injected parameters to member fields?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In my code, I'm often finding myself setting up classes which utilize constructor-based dependency injection and have a number of dependencies coming in. It's not uncommon for me to end up with something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IMyDependency1 _dependency1;
    private readonly IMyDependency2 _dependency2;

    public MyClass(IMyDependency1 dependency1, IMyDependency2 dependency2)
    {
        _dependency1 = dependency1;
        _dependency2 = dependency2;
    }
}
```

This, while obviously necessary from a functionality perspective, feels like needless boilerplate. I've used libraries in other languages such as Java which help with this by offering annotations/attributes to handle the bindings for you. What I'm looking for is something that handles this in C# (preferably compatible with .net core), something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [FromConstructor]
    private readonly IMyDependency1 _dependency1;

    [FromConstructor]
    private readonly IMyDependency2 _dependency2;

    public MyClass(IMyDependency1 dependency1, IMyDependency2 dependency2)
    {
        //whatever Bind() call required here
    }
}
```

Bonus points if the presence of the annotation can result in the package autogenerating the required constructor meaning I can avoid needing to write a constructor at all in the case where all the constructor is doing is handling dependency binding.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459625/property-injection-in-asp-net-core), the answer is no and this question also gives some reasons why not....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any library which provides such functionality out of the box, but you try write one by your self, with small addition of AOP library named [`PostSharp`](https://www.postsharp.net/).

Basic idea is this: [apply an PostSharp attribute aspect to a given properties](https://www.postsharp.net/architecture), get the `DeclaringType` information, and [create a constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.constructorbuilder.aspx) on fly and emit it to your library. You can even create binding for your IoC container at the same time. Here is a question on SO about applying the [aspects on types in PostSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13384762/213550).

The downsides of such a solution are that `PostSharp` Architecture packet [isn't free](https://www.postsharp.net/purchase), `PostSharp` do it's work after compile, so it basically partially overwrites your library, and I'm not sure would you be able to emit constructor to your existing library or you need to create a separate one. Also .Net Core version of `PostSharp` is [in experimental phase](https://www.postsharp.net/integration/platforms).